# Fellow Project Administrator Cannot Delete User Stories (But I can)

Tags: azure-devops, permissions, administrator

I have an Administrator in an Administrative group with the Boards Permissions all set to "Allow (inherited)".

He cannot delete a User Story he created.

We both inherit the permissions from the same "Project Administrators" group.

I can delete stories as expected, but he doesn't even have the option in the drop-down.

Any idea why that would be?

UPDATE: I had a co-worker who is also an administrator with the same permissions as the affected Admin, and they were able to create and delete stories. So now we've verified that 2/3 of the Admins tested with this setting are able to delete, but the other is not.  The affected admin doesn't even have delete as an option when selecting "…" for an item.

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution.

Under Organization Settings > Users, the user in question was listed as a Stakeholder.

I had to promote him to Basic.

This solved the problem, and it might not be discoverable as the cause of the problem if a Project admin is not also an Org admin.